# How to show two bar chart side by side and compare them

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, charts

```
n=20;
list4 = {1.0526315786138172`, 0.5555555541663151`, 
0.3921568573075441`, 0.3124999796694264`, 0.2666665956722264`, 
0.23809500179235274`, 0.21977946619291758`, 0.2083310131665477`, 
0.20201326465717925`, 0.19997974697283805`, 0.20196217882320022`, 
0.2081693710585961`, 0.2193206639825469`, 0.23680903638241013`, 
0.2630389206743215`, 0.3020407644466671`, 0.36053999654125235`, 
0.4497305815804302`, 0.5879697753001203`};
list6 = Table[i, {i, 1, n - 1, 1}];
list5 = {0.9803217312564441`, 0.48891346032810523`, 
0.3300180618700858`, 0.2538647255576357`, 0.21065863530452583`, 
0.18392405414737623`, 0.16670585871480148`, 0.15562904373342287`, 
0.1489303764483624`, 0.1456860926197184`, 0.14548235706853685`, 
0.14828607398305826`, 0.15443178324443788`, 0.16471559675381398`, 
0.18063370181566454`, 0.20487923953730616`, 0.24232040074890238`, 
0.30183038312423593`, 0.3993773303034516`};
list6 = Table[i, {i, 1, n - 1, 1}];
BarChart[{list4, list5}, 
ChartStyle -> {Directive[RGBColor[0.8, 0, 0] , Opacity[.5]], 
 Directive[RGBColor[0., 0.8, 0] , Opacity[.5]]}, 
ChartLabels -> {"1", "", "", "", "5", "", "", "", "", "10", "", "", 
  "", "", "15", "", "", "", "19"}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"i", 
  "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[OverscriptBox[\(f\), \(_\)], \(n, i\)]\)"}, 
FrameStyle -> Thickness[.003], 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium], 
 BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 40, 
  FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, 
 ChartLegends -> Placed[{"Selection"}, {0.5, 0.9}]]
```

I want to compare the two data list5 and list4 and show in chart side by side.

Comment: When you say "side by side", do you have this in mind? `PairedBarChart[list4, list5]` . What do you mean by " ... and compare them": Do you have a metric for comparison?

Comment: list6 is the x axis which is same for both of them. So each value of list6 should have two bars side by side one correspond to list4 and other correspond to list5 which basically means i dont want both the bars to overlap each other whereas to come side by side

Comment: Try: `BarChart[Transpose[{list4, list5}]]` and `list6` is not evaluating. What is the value of `n`? And I am not sure why you have it twice (or at all).

Comment: Sorry, I have given the value of n, actually lists are generated from a complicated formulas. I forgot to mention the n. Thanks  a lot for the transpose command. This is what I need but i would like to mark the x axis also

Comment: How shall I write chart labels in the case of Transpose. And also how can I increase the width of the bar in the case of transpose

Comment: `ChartLabels -> {"a", "b"}` but I am guessing this is not what you want.

Comment: The only thing left is increasing the width of the bars

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put labels at location 3 for your data:

```
data = Transpose[{list4, list5, IntegerString[Range[1, 19], 10, 2]}]

BarChart[Labeled[{#1, #2}, #3, Below] & @@@ data
 , Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, True}}
 , AspectRatio -> 4/10
 , FrameStyle -> Thickness[.001]
 , LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium]
 , ChartStyle -> {Red, Blue}
 , BarSpacing -> {0, 0.3}
 , BaseStyle -> {
   FontWeight -> "Bold"
   , FontSize -> 40
   , FontFamily -> "Calibri"
   }
 , FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {None, None}}
 , ImageSize -> 800
 , GridLines -> Automatic
 , ChartLegends -> Placed[{"a", "b"}, {0.9, 0.9}]
 ]
```

[image]

You can experiment with spacings and styles to get the desired look.

Comment: Could you please also mention How shall I mark some points on the red bar.

Comment: Try: `Epilog -> {
  Text[Style["some text", Darker@Cyan, 12], {13, 0.5}]
  , Darker@Cyan
  , Arrowheads[0.02]
  , Arrow[{{12.6, 0.47}, {12.6, 0.24}}]
  }` . By the way there are automatic `Tooltip` features activated for each data item.

Comment: Final querry. I want to mark these points on red bars The ticks does not seems to be unispaced. listst = {1.0526315786138172`, 0.5555555541663151`, 
  0.3921568573075441`, 0.3124999796694264`, 0.2666665956722264`, 
  0.23809500179235274`, 0.21977946619291758`, 0.2083310131665477`, 
  0.20201326465717925`, 0.19997974697283805`, 0.20196217882320022`, 
  0.2081693710585961`, 0.2193206639825469`, 0.23680903638241013`, 
  0.2630389206743215`, 0.3020407644466671`, 0.36053999654125235`, 
  0.4497305815804302`, 0.5879697753001203`}.

Comment: You can start a separate question and provide a `minimal working example` of what you need. I think a barchart is a tool suited at best for crude visual comparisons only.